# Logging best practices for .NET application running in multiple threads

Tags: .net, logging

We have an application that logs to files currently using streamwriter. As we are looking at scaling up the application, the logging block is coming in the way. The application is multi-threaded and can perform with a thread-count which is in thousands. The thread-count does not hit the CPU as most of the responsibilities is to handle TCP sockets on the fly. But the logging is an issue as there is convergence here and performance of the individual threads is impacted for its TAT here.

I shall like to get input from all of you regarding what kind of architecture/design can be followed for the loggging.

I am thinking of using database as the logging sink. But the writer will have to have a locking mechanism I feel. I don't think, I should try creating large number of loggers in threads. Another option I am thinking of doing a pooling on top of the logger.

Should I also look at MSMQ kind of technologies to quickly move out the traffic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look at existing logging frameworks, such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) or Microsoft's [Enterprise Library Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647183.aspx). (I've used log4net a bit, but not the Logging Application Block.)

I very much doubt that your situation is unique, after all - and if you go for a third-party solution instead of a home-grown one, you'll be able to benefit from the experience of other developers.

If you *do* roll your own and want a producer/consumer model, you may want to look at the concurrent collections in .NET 4. As mhenrixon mentions though, you'll almost certainly have to find a balance between performance and reliability. If this is just for debug logs then it probably doesn't matter too much if you lose a few if the application shuts down abruptly - but obviously it's a different matter if the logs contain audit records which *have* to be persisted.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I am actually looking forward to start with something like log4net just to get the advantage of others' experience. In the same time, I also am looking at meeting my specific requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You should also consider [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), particularly NLog 2.0 (currently in Beta - since September).  Among other things, NLog 2.0 adds the ability to log [asynchronously](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/AsyncWrapper_target).  In essence, you would configure the Target(s) (equivalent to log4net Appender) to which you would like to log (file, database, etc).  Then, also via configuration, you "wrap" each Target with an asynchronous target wrapper.  NLog also has an option in the config file to make all logging asynchronous.

While we you are on the subject of logging, you might also consider using a logging abstraction like [Common.Logging for .NET](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/).  This gives you the option to defer the final decision on your underlying framework (log4net, NLog, etc) and also gives you the option to write your own logger (which can easily be exposed via Common.Logging).

Comment: The async logging is surely a great feature I am looking forward to. Thanks. I shall update once I do some POC on that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are after something that in log4net is called [Appender Buffering](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.BufferingForwardingAppender.html) thought that one is not fail safe if logging cannot be "lossy" I recommend using queues. I believe that any of the logging frameworks could easily be extended with MSMQ logging.